# Getting a prediction from Keras with a 1-D array

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I have the following code:

```
from numpy import loadtxt
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from time import sleep
dataset = loadtxt('dataset.csv', delimiter=',')
X = dataset[:,0:8]
y = dataset[:,8]
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(192, input_dim=8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, y, epochs=600, batch_size=10)
_, accuracy = model.evaluate(X, y)
print('Accuracy: %.2f' % (accuracy*100))
```

When I run it, it trains no problem, and most of the time I even get 100% accuracy, but I'm having trouble getting predictions from the model. As you can see by the following sample of the training data, the first 8 entries are inputs, and a 1 or 0 is the out put.

```
6,148,72,35,0,33.6,0.627,50,1
1,85,66,29,0,26.6,0.351,31,0
8,183,64,0,0,23.3,0.672,32,1
1,89,66,23,94,28.1,0.167,21,0
0,137,40,35,168,43.1,2.288,33,1
5,116,74,0,0,25.6,0.201,30,0
3,78,50,32,88,31.0,0.248,26,1
10,115,0,0,0,35.3,0.134,29,0
2,197,70,45,543,30.5,0.158,53,1
8,125,96,0,0,0.0,0.232,54,1
4,110,92,0,0,37.6,0.191,30,0
10,168,74,0,0,38.0,0.537,34,1
10,139,80,0,0,27.1,1.441,57,0
1,189,60,23,846,30.1,0.398,59,1
5,166,72,19,175,25.8,0.587,51,1
7,100,0,0,0,30.0,0.484,32,1
0,118,84,47,230,45.8,0.551,31,1
7,107,74,0,0,29.6,0.254,31,1
```

What I want to enter "6,148,72,35,0,33.6,0.627,50" into the code and have the model give me an output based on that. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, that was fast, but it occurred to me that I just needed to add another list define around the one that was already there, making it a 2D array, and allowing Keras to make a prediction.